# jQuery return with a line break

Tags: jquery

I have this function:

```
function(tooltipItem, data) {
     return 'line1' + "<br>" + 'line2';
}
```

Right now it is returning `line1<br>line2`.

How would I write the return so it displays like this?

```
line1
line2
```

Comment: use `.html()`, which since it's rendering as text, I assume you are not.

Comment: In any case, we really need to see how you're using this function to get an idea of how to fix it.

Comment: I'm just using it to return text, is that what you're asking? @Cauterite

Comment: @Andrea not exactly, because you're asking "How would I write the return so it displays like this?", we need to know what you're using to "display" the result.

Answer (score 1):

Set value inside  `html()` method of selected element or use JavaScript `innerHtml` property and `<br/>` will render newline.

If you are using output as string than use `\n` character for new line.

```
function(tooltipItem, data) {
     return 'line1' + "\n" + 'line2';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `\n` in place of `<br/>`.

Please check below snippet. You will find in alert line2 is in new line

```js
alert('line1' + "\n" + 'line2');
```